# Is there a html "tag" <card>?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

Is there a html "tag" `<card>`? I have seen (a well working) one [here](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/netflix-tech-blog-card).

However, I could not find `<card>` in any html documentation. Am I missing something?

Comment: With certain frameworks, `components`, as that link example appears to be, can be created for convenience. The same can be achieved with [HTML and CSS too](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp).

Comment: @PaulT. — [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), which are the part of the Web Components spec  you are taking about, must have a hyphen in their name. `<card>` is not a valid custom element name. It is just invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to answer without html sample
Could be just css style, like:

```
<card>
I'm the guy
</card>
```

css:

```
card {
font-size: 55px;
color: blue;
}
```

Fiddle sample https://jsfiddle.net/Precitools/f4hbqcmv/3/

Comment: Not my downvote, but why not add a stack snippet example here on stackoverflow without the need for an external site? ... that's what the `<>` icon is for on the text editor toolbar.